# Lambda expression is not recognizing right mouse button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, lambda, mouse

The following code creates a 5 by 5 grid of buttons from an array. I'm useing lambda expression to get the position of the button in array at the moment of mouse click. The problem is, that i need to know whether left or right mouse button were pressed. So far i have output from left button, but no response from right.

```
    Button[] grid5x5 = new Button[25];
    void Spawn5x5Grid()
    {
        lblSize.Text = "5x5";
        currentGridSize = GridSize.grid5x5;
        currentGameState = GameState.GameOn;

        // Position of the first button
        int x = 50, y = 150;
        // Index of the button for the loop
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                grid5x5[count] = new Button
                {
                    Size = new Size(31,31),
                    Location = new Point(x, y)
                };
                this.Controls.Add(grid5x5[count]);

                grid5x5[count].MouseClick += (o, ee) =>
                {
                    Button button = o as Button;

                    int index = Array.IndexOf(grid5x5, button);

                    if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Left button");   
                    }
                    else if (ee.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Right button");
                    }

                };

                count++;
                x = x + 31;
            }
            x = 50;
            y = y + 31;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps detecting what mouse button has been pressed inside the form helps, or create some sort of container for the grid instead of detecting it for the entire form.

Comment: @MoreOrLessYou thanks for the link. I'll check if it work.

Comment: @MoreOrLessYou It worked. Had to change from MouseClick to MouseUp. Thanks!